# Как на чистом Си заполнить массив содержимым памяти?

Tags: массивы, c

Необходимо заполнить массив целого типа на 10 элементов содержимым памяти, начиная с ячейки с адресом 0xf000. Каким образом можно это осуществить?

P.S. Память ЭВМ при этом условимся считать 640кб. Если это что-то меняет.

Comment: Здесь дело не в "чистоте" Си, а в операционной системе. Доступ к физической памяти осуществляется путем использования системных вызовов и/или библиотечных функций, с ними связанных. Информации в вопросе явно недостаточно.

Comment: Какой памяти: виртуальной или физической?

Comment: Для прикладной программы в более-менее распространенных ОС адрес 0xf000 будет доступен только в ДОС (если ее можно считать распространенной). В остальных получите сигнал SIGSEGV.

Comment: Во-во. Кстати, а почему так? Я программирование в ДОСе совсем плохо знаю.

Comment: В ДОС нет защиты памяти.

Comment: Это понятно. А почему в защищенном режиме не может быть виртуального адреса 0хf000 ?

Comment: По поводу longjmp в обработчике сигналов. Надо в такой ситуации использовать siglongjmp и sigsetjmp. Подробнее см. у Керриска.

Comment: To @mikillskegg, 
Про ДОС и защищенный режим ничего не знаю.

Просто я знаю, что в Windows можно читать, начиная с адреса 0x10000. (Вычислил). В Линукс (64-bit) попытка вычислить такой адрес не удалась. (Пока не понимаю почему). Перехватываю SIGSEGV делаю longjmp(), увеличиваю указатель -> "Oшибка сегментирования". Почему повторно не отрабатывает обработчик сигнала ??? (повторно signal() вызываю).

Идеи есть ?

--

Лимит... Поэтому удаляю и правлю...

Спасибо, пара sigsetjmp()/siglongjmp() работает. В Ubuntu 10.04 2.6.32 gcc 4.4.3
First readable addr 0x00400000 (4194304)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если речь идет о простой виртуальной памяти процесса, то так

```
int buf[10];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) buf[i] = *((int*) 0xf000 + i);
```

Или так

```
int buf[10];
memcpy (buf, (void*) 0xf000, sizeof(int)*10);
```

Comment: а разве не `memset` используется для этих целей?

Comment: memset заполняет байты указанного в параметрах участка памяти значением, указанным там же.

Answer (score -3):

Если я все правильно понял то так:

```
main(){
 int *a = 0;
 int arr[10];
 int i=0;
 for(i=0; i <= 10; i++)
 arr[i]=a++;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы буфер заполняете значениям адреса, а не значениями ячеек по этим адресам. Надо разыменовывать указатель.